# Can't establish database error. What did cause it?

Tags: mysql, database, wordpress, phpmyadmin, multisite

as editing my `wordpress` `multisite` when suddenly had this error. Searched for fix and executed the mysql restart command which fixed the issue and the website is running again. As this happened so suddenly, I would like to know how to prevent this kind of error in future.

When tried accessing the `phpmyadmin` it showed:

`mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2002): No such file or directory`

When checked the status in SSH, it said `failed (Result: exit-code)`

What could have cause this issue?

It is showing one error and one notice:

> Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#613 count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable Backtrace ./libraries/sql.lib.php#2128: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array) ./libraries/sql.lib.php#2062: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse( array, boolean true, string 'wp_wordpress', string 'wp_3_options',

Comment: What is `myphpadmin`? Do you mean `phpMyAdmin`?

Comment: yes, I meant phpmyadmin. Just had the same error. I guess it appears when there are too many task on the website. How to prevent it?

Comment: sounds like MySQL is crashing for some reason. Have you checked the error logs

Comment: It is showing one error and one notice: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59306330/error-and-notice-in-phpmyadmin-database-how-to-fix-it

Comment: In the question please, more space, easier to read.

Comment: I have a few doubts, the wordpress is running? the database is working?

Comment: Does phpMyAdmin work now that your MySQL service is restarted?

Answer (score 0):

San,

I think you shoud try this.

```
change localhost to 127.0.0.1 in config.inc.php
```

> The reason for this is that phpmyadmin tries to connect to the mysql.socket if you use localhost. If you use 127.0.0.1 PMA makes a TCP connection which should work.