# Error and notice in Phpmyadmin database. How to fix it?

Tags: wordpress, phpmyadmin, multisite

It shows:

> Warning in ./libraries/sql.lib.php#613
>    count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Backtrace

```
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2128: PMA_isRememberSortingOrder(array)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2062: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'wp_wordpress',
string 'wp_3_options',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_3_options`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#221: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'wp_wordpress',
string 'wp_3_options',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_3_options`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

And also:

> Notice in `./libraries/DisplayResults.php#1229`
>    Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Backtrace

```
./libraries/DisplayResults.php#1349: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->_getTableHeadersForColumns(
array,
array,
array,
array,
array,
boolean false,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_3_options` ',
)
./libraries/DisplayResults.php#4427: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->_getTableHeaders(
array,
array,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_3_options` ',
array,
array,
array,
boolean false,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1686: PMA\libraries\DisplayResults->getTable(
,
array,
array,
boolean false,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#1980: PMA_getHtmlForSqlQueryResultsTable(
,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
array,
boolean true,
string '794',
integer 25,
NULL,
,
array,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2199: PMA_getQueryResponseForResultsReturned(
,
array,
string 'wp_wordpress',
string 'wp_3_options',
NULL,
NULL,
,
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
string '794',
integer 25,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_3_options`',
NULL,
)
./libraries/sql.lib.php#2062: PMA_executeQueryAndGetQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'wp_wordpress',
string 'wp_3_options',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_3_options`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
./sql.php#221: PMA_executeQueryAndSendQueryResponse(
array,
boolean true,
string 'wp_wordpress',
string 'wp_3_options',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string '',
string './themes/pmahomme/img/',
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
string 'SELECT * FROM `wp_3_options`',
NULL,
NULL,
)
```

What this error and Notice mean and how to fix them? How do they affect my site?

Comment: phpmyadmin is not a database but just a tool to interact with mysql databases. Also, how multisite would be related to this question?

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version are you using and what are the exact steps I could take to reproduce this problem? Can you cause it on the phpMyAdmin demo server at https://demo.phpmyadmin.net ?